# ELI5: What is an $l^p$ space

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I have already asked a similar question. Still, I have been thinking about $l^p$ spaces all summer, and I still don't have a grasp of it. I thought $l^p$ spaces are a generalization of Euclidean space. If that is the case, I don't understand the relationship between an Lp space and this famous graph:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#/media/File:Vector-p-Norms_qtl1.svg

If  $l^p$spaces are not a generalization of Euclidean space, could someone *please* tell me what  $l^p$ spaces are and how the linked graph motivates understanding?

To all those who may contribute, I thank you, in advance, VERY much for your insight.

Comment: That image has something to do with l^p-norms, which are related to, but different from the l^p-spaces. The image might help you understand l^p-norms, but I don't think it will help you understand l^p-spaces.

Comment: Do you want a definition in a general measure space, or specifically in $\mathbb{R^n}$? If in  $\mathbb{R^n}$, then for $p\geq 1$ you can define a norm like this: if $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ then $||x||_p=(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. When $p=2$ this is exactly the Euclidean norm. The graph shows how the unit circle looks for different $p$-norms.

Comment: Those graphs are all circles ;)

The circle is set of all points at the given distance from a given point. However, the definition of distance changes with $p$. On the picture you can see  what the circle (centered in $(0,0)$ with radius $1$) looks like if $p=1, 1.5, 2, 3, 6$ and the limit-case ("$p=\infty$").

Comment: The square-integrable functions $L^2$ are a kind of generalization of Euclidean spaces, whose norm is defined by summing/integrating the squares of function values.  In particular this norm is given (in both settings) by an inner product (or dot product, for the finite-dimensional case).  The $L^p$ spaces are functions with finite $p$-power integrals, and they have a norm for $p\ge 1$ but not given by an inner product except for the special case $p=2$.  Does that help?

Comment: @Thorgott thanks for making the distinction. What I really need is an understanding first of the spaces and *then* the norms. But I need to have them explains in a non-formal way. I have three concurrent books, each of them good in their own way, but none of them offers me what I need in this case: the most primitive explanation possible for what these things *are*.

Comment: The norms are needed to define the spaces, so I suggest you try understanding them first.

Comment: One thing that may seem obvious, but no one has said it.  The graphs show the unit balls of $\ell^p$ on $\mathbb R^2$.  You can also visualize the unit balls of $\ell^p$ on $\mathbb R^3$, but with more difficulty.  In higher dimensions, it is impossible to visualize (well it is for me).  And unfortunately there are a lot of interesting phenomena in higher dimensions that are extremely hard to see from these low dimensional pictures.

Comment: There is a sense in which $\ell^p$ is just generalization of Euclidean space for the sake of generalization.  But then you discover that $L^p$ spaces are extremely useful in proving solutions to PDE.

Comment: There is also the notion of Orlicz spaces, which generalize $L^p$ spaces.  Then you discover that inequalities like Holder's inequality don't exactly work out (the inequalities exists, but without constants equal to 1).  Then you think that maybe $L^p$ spaces are natural after all.

Answer (score 2):

The $l^p$ space is a special case of Minkowski space, all these "non-Euclidean "geometries have been derived based on using the first four Euclidean postulates together with various negations of the fifth. take a look at https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/minkowski-geometry/BEB8FE99553CABD2BECD623887C879B8

imagine you are in a space that is not homogenous, so distance is not the same in every direction. try to have a look on the spherical geometries and also the hyperbolic plane.

in the Euclidean plane the minimal distance between two points is just the segment when you are in $l^p$ space the minimal distance are arcs of the $l^q$ disk passing through the two points (such that l^q is the dual of l^p)

in general, when your unit disk is the euclidean disc everything is Clair (humain are euclidean) you can compute angles, area, perimeter, curvature the orthogonality between two vectors ...
when your unit disk is just a convex body you lose a lot of things, first the symmetry of the orthogonality ....

Comment: wonderful answer! Thank you for taking the time to write your response. Everything you say commutes with my developing intuition on the matter and gives me a firmer apprehension of what I am meant to understand as the underlying concepts.